# what is different between two code block seperately build on tensorflow API and keras API? my compute result has large gap

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am building a model to classify sequence class. firstly i build the model use keras API. As we know the keras API packed the tensorflow function, but when i convert the keras code to tensorflow API, i found the result of two framwork is different. Below is the key code.

tensorflow code

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, time_steps], name='x_input')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_classes], name='y_label')


定义网络结构
def rnn_model(x):
    x = tf.one_hot(x,api_vob_size)
    rnn_cell_fw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
    rnn_cell_bw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
    # 将输入送入rnn，得到输出与中间状态，输出shape为[batch_size, time_steps, rnn_size]
    outputs, states = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(rnn_cell_fw,rnn_cell_bw, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    # 获取最后一个时刻的输出，输出shape为[batch_size, rnn_size]
    outputs1 = tf.concat(outputs, 2)
    output = tf.transpose(outputs1, [1, 0, 2])[-1]
    # 全连接层，最终输出大小为[batch_size, num_classes]
    fc_w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2*rnn_size, num_classes]))
    fc_b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))
    return tf.matmul(output, fc_w) + fc_b `

# 构建网络
logits= rnn_model(x)
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

# 定义损失函数与优化器
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits, name='cross_entropy'))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op,name='optimizer_min')
```

#keras API

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=150), merge_mode='concat'))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64)
```

so why two code block has different result. thank you for answer !!!!

Comment: Your TF code uses sigmoid cross entropy and the Keras version uses categorical cross entropy.

Comment: Actually @xdurch0 is correct. Change the `tf.nn.sigmoid_...` to `tf.nn.softmax_...`.

Comment: @xdurch0 @today oh, thank you for the answer. I have tried two kind of cross entropy. `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits()`and `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`. a question--later is same as keras compile API loss='categorical_crossentropy'？